# meaning of update when value of hbm2ddl.auto set to update

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, nhibernate-configuration

In configuration file i am using this

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Although there was no table in my database, but still with the update command it creates the table in database.

what i thought that hbm2ddl.auto= "update" use only to update the schema and to create the same we use "create".

i am still confused how that table come into existence.

or update is the reason to create the table.

Please help

Comment: update means update the schema to match what is needed. If there is no schema it will create one, if there is one it will be  updated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto possible values and what they do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do)

Comment: not a duplicate deinum .... in that question meaning of update is not clear i.e If there is no schema it will create one, if there is one it will be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the attached image, tried documented as much as i can.

[image]